# Can't exit while loop with "toggleButton1" in STM32CubeIDE and touchGFX

Tags: stm32

I am using a STM32H750B-DK board and in the following program, I am trying to exit the while loop when I click "toggleButton1" again. It seems that the button is not responding once I am in the loop.

```
void Screen1View::relay_1()
{
  if(toggleButton1.getState()){
    while(1){
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_SET);
      HAL_Delay(1000);
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
      HAL_Delay(1000);
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOJ, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_SET);
      HAL_Delay(1000);
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOJ, GPIO_PIN_2, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
      HAL_Delay(1000);
      if(toggleButton1.getState() == 0){
        break;
      }
    }
  }
  else HAL_GPIO_WritePin(GPIOD, GPIO_PIN_3, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
}
```

I tried to use "goto" but that also didn't work.

Comment: if it doesn't exit the loop, the one and only conclusion is that .getState() never returns zero. Why? That's for you to answer, you didn't post the code of the .getState(). Alternatively, something just calls relay_1() again as soon as you exit it. Basically, the problem is almost certainly in the parts of code that you left out.

Comment: The only other code outside the one that I have posted is in Screen1View.hpp where I defined the function relay_1 and in STM32.ioc where I set the pin that I am using as output.

Comment: I forgot to add. The problem is that I can't even interact with the button on the STM32 screen when I am in the loop

Comment: Then you know for a fact that `toggleButton1.getState()` never returns zero, otherwise it would exit the loop. Why does it never return zero? Well, you have the code of `toggleButton1.getState()` somewhere. So present it or find the problem in there on your own.

Comment: well, regardless of that, we know that function never returns zero, otherwise you would have exited the loop. So something is going on there.

Comment: Thank you for help. Ill try something else and update the Q if I find the A.

Comment: Also, having while(1) in general is not great, as it halts all the drawing and button reactions while you're in it. Your program doesn't handle screen touches while inside it, because it's, well, inside your loop and not running through its touch handler and drawing routines. Be careful with this approach.

Comment: Ok, I understand. WIill keep that in mind.